# Crear un objeto Java a partir de una lista de otros objetos

Tags: java, map

Tengo una clase `Torres` que está compuesta por otras clases `Plaques` y `Memories` todas heredan de `Producto` :

```
public class Torres extends Producto {
    private Plaques plaques;
    private Memories memories;

    public Torres(String codiIntern, String descripcio, String nomFab, double preuC, double preuBrut, int estoc,Plaques plaques,Memories memories) {
        super(codiIntern, descripcio, nomFab, preuC, preuBrut, estoc);
        this.memories = memories;
        this.plaques = plaques;
    }
}
```

También dispongo de un `TreeMap` que representa son los componentes con los que se formara el objeto `Torres`, formado con diferentes `Plaques` y `Memories`. La clave es el codiIntern, y el valor son unicamente objetos `Plaques` y `Memories`

```
torres = new TreeMap<String,Producto>();
```

Mi duda sería cómo hacer un método que me cree un objeto de `Torres` con todos los elementos de la lista `TreeMap`. Si por ejemplo hay 2 `Plaques` y 1 `Memories` deberia de crear una Torre que tenga esas 2 `Plaques` y 1 `Memories`.

Comment: Eso depende que tipos de objetos tienes en la lista y con que _key_ aparecen. Me imagino que existe también _Plaques extends Producto_ y _Memories extends Producto_?

Comment: No entiendo lo que intentas hacer. Asumiendo que hay 2 o más instancias de `Plaques` en tu mapa, ¿cómo identificarías cuál de esos debería pertenecer a tu instancia de `Torres`? ¿Podrías brindar más información para comprender tu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es que no queda muy clara la pregunta y además falta información sobre las clases `Plaques` y `Memories`, pero si lo he entendido bien, lo que quieres es construir objetos `Torres` con la información que tienes en el mapa de objetos `Plaques` y `Memories` y tu duda es de como saber cual es de cada tipo para moverlo a una propiedad u otra. Para saber el tipo tendrías que usar `instanceof`.

Si todos los objetos de la colección pertenecen al mismo objeto `Torres`podrías cambiar los objetos por colecciones y añadir usando propiedades en lugar de añadir los objetos directamente en el constructor. La clase quedaría así:

```
public class Torres extends Producto {
    private List<Plaques> plaques = new ArrayList<Plaques>();
    private List<Memories> memories = new ArrayList<Memories>();

    public List<Plaques> getPlaques() {
        return plaques;
    }

    public void setPlaques(List<Plaques> plaques) {
        this.plaques = plaques;
    }

    public List<Memories> getMemories() {
        return memories;
    }

    public void setMemories(List<Memories> memories) {
        this.memories = memories;
    }

    public Torres(String codiIntern, String descripcio, String nomFab, double preuC, double preuBrut, int estoc) {
        super(codiIntern, descripcio, nomFab, preuC, preuBrut, estoc);
    }
}
```

Y podrías recorrerla así:

```
Torres newTorre = new Torres(null, null, null, 0, 0, 0);
Map<String, Producto> torres = new TreeMap<String, Producto>();

for(Producto myTorres: torres.values()) {
    if(myTorres instanceof Plaques) {
        newTorre.getPlaques().add((Plaques) myTorres);
    } else {
        newTorre.getMemories().add((Memories) myTorres);
    }
}
```

Esto, asumiendo que los objetos `Plaques` y `Memories` extienden de `Producto`.

Comment: He mofidicado la pregunta, a ver si ahora se entiende mejor. En el mapa no hay objetos `Torres` solamente `Plaques` y `Memories`.

Comment: Con el nuevo comentario creo que la solución es más simple. Yo cambiaría los objetos `Plaques` y  `Memories` por colecciones de objetos `Plaques` y  `Memories`. Los expones como dos propiedades y los quitas del constructor.

Lo demás es más o menos como te comenté antes pero más fácil. Solo tendrías que recorrer la colección identificando el tipo con ìnstanceof`y añadirlos al objeto `Torres` usando las propiedades creadas antes.

Comment: No entiendo cuando dices cambiar los objetos por coleccciones de objetos, soy algo novato en Java y segun que cosas se me escapan. Luego en lo de exponer como propiedades es como lo tengo pero quitandolo del constructor? Y por ultimo entiendo que hay que hacer un for al TreeMap e ir añadiendo los elementos al objeto `Torres`, aunque no se muy bien como hacer esto. Gracias

Comment: Te he cambiado la respuesta. A ver si te sirve eso.